# What happened to Juuzawa Juu at the end?

Tags: denpa-teki-na-kanojo

At the end of the anime,

> Juuzawa Juu was hit by a car/truck and he was shown talking to Ame on the ground.

Are we supposed to assume that he

> died,

or was it left as a cliffhanger that was never resolved (only three novels were written and that how it was left off)?

Also, how did Ame know that Juuzawa was in danger at the end? Was that supposed to show that she actually did know him from a different life or was it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Three Musketeers arrived at the scene, standing in front of Shiraishi's dead body, Kirishima observed that

> Not many people believe in divine retribution. That's because God is a lazy fellow. However, he does a good job every once in a while.

Therefore, it was clear that the truck turned away from Juuzawa and crushed the nearby Shiraishi into a bloody pulp. Juuzawa was left intact (or not fatally wounded) after the accident.

The anime explicitly stated at the conclusion of the second episode that Ochibana knew Juuzawa was in danger only because of their bond from their previous lives.

Answer (score 1):

The truck diverts in the end, thus running over Shirashi senpai.

It is shown in the end with her hand filled with blood crushed in the truck, thus by pushing Juu on the road, she actually saved him (unintentionally) as the driver tries to avoid hitting Juuzawa and loses control over the truck and rams it into the girl.

Thats the divine retribution talked about in the end.